# SQL injection not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql, injection

I've created a test site in order to learn about SQLi and then protect against it. I may be misunderstanding how it is supposed to behave but at present I'm not getting the results I expect.

The page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>

<h1>SQL Injection Test Site</h1>
<h2>Login Form</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit"></form>

<?php
$db = mysql_connect(***, ***, ***); 
if(!$db){ 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}else{
    mysql_select_db(***);  
}

if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_data 
                            WHERE username = '$username' 
                               AND password = '$password'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    //we would now process the login if details matched
    echo "Logged in: " . $result['username'];
    var_dump($result);
}
?>

</body></html>
```

The table in the database:

[image: http://imgur.com/FvIbCuz]

The input:

```
username: admin
password: ' OR '1'='1
```

My expectation is that it would find the admin user and then accept the input from the password field as '1'='1 should evaluate to true. It actually returns the result for the first entry in the table, username JBloggs. This is the bit I don't understand.

Can anyone point out a fault in the code or logic that is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fault in the code. You are using the **OR** condition. For the first row having the data of the user JBloggs, the username is not admin but **1=1** is true for the first record. Since the two conditions have an OR between them, any single true condition will make the whole statement true that is why you are getting the record of the first row.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. So is there any way to target the query at the admin user only? I can't see how if the query passes over each row and will pass on the OR true. A lot of tutorials online seem to suggest you can output the contents of a table but I've yet to be successful in trying.

Comment: ' OR ('1'='1' AND username=admin)-- should give you the data for admin user